# Converting a for scriptlet based for loop to JSTL c:forEach loop

Tags: jsp, jstl

I am trying to convert a scriptlet based for loop to JSTL c:forEach loop but the results are getting messed up in the html table.

## Scriptlet Based For loop:

```
 for (int i = 1; i < extraTDs; i++) {
     %><%= openCloseTD%><%
 }
```

## Jstl for loop used:

```
<c:forEach  var="i" begin="1" end="${extraTDs}">
    ${openCloseTD}
</c:forEach>
```

Please guide.

Comment: Define "getting messed up". Example input, example output, expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end index in the c:foreach is *inclusive* (cf. [JSTL documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/)). The JSTL code makes one more iteration than the scriptlet based code.

To get the same behaviour, you should use:

```
<c:forEach  var="i" begin="1" end="${extraTDs - 1}">
    ${openCloseTD}
</c:forEach>
```