# Displaying List elements in JSTL <c:/forEach> with counter variable

Tags: java, list, jsp, foreach, jstl

I have a scriptlet for-loop that displays movie schedules from a `List<Schedule>`.

```jsp
<%
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Schedule> scheduleList = 
        (ArrayList<Schedule>) session.getAttribute("scheduleList");

    for (int ctr = 0; ctr < scheduleList.size(); ctr++) {
%>

<tr>
    <td class="center">
        <input type="radio" name="selection" value="<%=ctr%>" required title="Please select a schedule." />
    </td>
    <td><%=scheduleList.get(ctr).getMallId()%></td>
    <td class="center"><%=scheduleList.get(ctr).getScheduleCinema()%></td>
    <td>PHP <%=scheduleList.get(ctr).getSchedulePrice()%></td>
    <td><%=scheduleList.get(ctr).getScheduleDate()%></td>
    <td><%=scheduleList.get(ctr).getScheduleTime()%></td>
    <td class="center"><%=scheduleList.get(ctr).getScheduleSeats()%></td>
</tr>

<%
    }
%>
```

Here is the `Schedule` bean object for reference:

```java
public class Schedule {

    private int scheduleId;
    private int movieId;
    private String mallId;
    private int scheduleCinema;
    private BigDecimal schedulePrice;
    private Date scheduleDate;
    private Time scheduleTime;
    private int scheduleSeats;

    // getters and setters
}
```

I have managed to convert it to JSTL with my desired number of iterations ([related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006212/converting-a-for-scriptlet-based-for-loop-to-jstl-cforeach-loop)).

```jsp
<c:forEach var="ctr" begin="0" end="${scheduleList.size()-1}">
<tr>
    <td class="center">
        <input type="radio" name="selection" value="${ctr}" required title="Please select a schedule." />
    </td>
    <td>${schedule.mallId}</td>
    <td>${schedule.scheduleCinema}</td>
    <td>${schedule.schedulePrice}</td>
    <td>${schedule.scheduleDate}</td>
    <td>${schedule.scheduleTime}</td>
    <td>${schedule.scheduleSeats}</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Firefox Inspector:**

```jsp
<tr>

    <td class="center">
        <input type="radio" title="Please select a schedule." required="" value="0" name="selection"></input>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>

</tr>
<tr>

    <td class="center">
        <input type="radio" title="Please select a schedule." required="" value="1" name="selection"></input>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>

</tr>
```

Unfortunately, the schedule details are not displaying.
*How do I display the data of each `Schedule` element from the `List<Schedule>` in JSTL?*

(The `ctr` is important by the way, its value will be needed in the next action.)

Comment: Also, more moderns versions of EL use `#` instead of `$`

Comment: I have added the generated HTML from Firefox Inspector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
<c:forEach var="ctr" begin="0" end="${scheduleList.size()-1}">
```

Use:

```
<c:forEach var="schedule" items="${scheduleList}" varStatus="ctr">
<tr>
<td class="center">
    <input type="radio" name="selection" value="${ctr.index}" required title="Please select a schedule." />
</td>
```

For ctr you could maintain separate counter variable and increment within your forEach.

Comment: Hi, I've been using this approach for my other JSTL iterations, but this one particularly needs a `ctr`. Could you kindly update your answer to show what you meant with the `ctr` variable? I'm particularly new to JSTL.

Comment: Minor typo by the way, `var="schedule"items="${scheduleList}"` needs whitespace. :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. You are right. I have just modified and corrected the typo.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `varStatus` as well as `var` variable in `c:forEach`

```
varStatus="loop"
```

and use it as `${loop.index}`

e.g. see the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18825950/how-to-get-a-index-value-from-foreach-loop-in-jstl)

Comment: Thanks, I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600738/use-jstl-foreach-loops-varstatus-as-an-id) post is also helpful for anyone reading this thread.