# List not displaying the properties even with size 0

Tags: java

```
List<Object> result = (List<Object>)guestSession.Available_RoomType(startDateString, endDateString, name);

             List<Roomtype> new_room;
                            List<? extends Object> list = result;
                            new_room = (List<Roomtype>) list;

    %>
    <table>
        <%if(new_room!=null){
                            for(Roomtype r : new_room){%>
        <tr>

            <td><%= r.getName() %></td>
            <td><%= r.getDescription() %></td>
            <td><%= r.getPrice() %></td>
        </tr>

   <%}
        }%>
    </table><%
        }
    %>
```

new_room has size 0 when i debug it but the properties are not displaying. the compiler jumps everything in the `tr`. Please any reason for this because the page comes blank after.

Answer (score 0):

First, please don't use scriptlets. Second,

```
List<Roomtype> new_room = (List<Roomtype>) guestSession.Available_RoomType(
        startDateString, endDateString, name);
%>
<table>
    <% if(new_room != null) {
       for(Roomtype r : new_room){%>
```

Finally, I suggest you take a look at [`<c:forEach>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27165719/displaying-list-elements-in-jstl-c-foreach-with-counter-variable) as it supports iterating a collection.